# How to fix the Excel goes to Not-responding state when the Macro is running?

Tags: vba, excel

The Excel sheet is getting Not-responding while the Macro is running, Once the macro has run, it back to the sheet with the answers.

Comment: That can happen when the macro takes a long time to execute. What is the question?

Comment: It is not running for a long time, just running time is one min..Is there any function or code to overcome this ?

Comment: Do you want the macro to run faster or do you want to interact with the worksheet while the macro is running??

Comment: Just I dont want my excel to not responding while macro running ..thats it

Comment: plz show some code of the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running some kind of loop. Try inserting a `DoEvents` somewhere in the loop and see if this helps.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 1000
    ' do stuff that takes a long time

    DoEvents
Next i
```